# how to store databind value in other variable in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

```
    <asp:DataList ID="dlAssignftp" Visible="false" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="Vertical"
            HorizontalAlign="left" CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="1" Width="100%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <ul class="gallery clearfix slideshow">
                    <li>
<a href='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "Image Path") %>' rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]">                   
                        <asp:Image ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "Image Path") %>' ID="imgftp"
                            runat="server" Height="100px" Width="100px" Visible="true" />
                         </a>                         
                    </li>        
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn_ftpimg" runat="server" Text="Select" TextAlign="Right" AutoPostBack="true" GroupName='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "Image Path") %>' OnCheckedChanged="rbtn_ftpimg_Changed" />            
                </ul>                    
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:DataList>
```

in the above **ascx code** , how can i store the **'<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "Image Path") %>'** value in some other variable, or simply how can i print the ImageUrl path ?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood your question. Have you tried `imgftp.ImageUrl` from codebehind?

Comment: actually it is a live site which already shows images which are loaded using FTP, and the ascx shows the img in a datalist, my wrk is to place radio button for each image(as no of imgs and img loc may vary), and wen the rB is selected the details for the appropriate img shud be shown in a alert box, do u have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

use the `hidden` value control of `asp.net` and store the value on it.

```
 <asp:hiddenfield id="ValueHiddenField" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "Image Path") %>' runat="server"/>
```

Use `DataList_ItemDataBound` event to get the value of each hidden field

```
Protected void Item_Bound(Object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
      {
         if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
             e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
         {

            // Retrieve the ValueHiddenField control in the current DataListItem.
            HiddenField imgPath = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("ValueHiddenField");
            string path = imgPath.Value;
         }
      }
```

To get more details read [this..](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemdatabound.aspx)

Comment: does it store dada bind values?